# Regular minimal stutters while dual monitors are turned on

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors

### Summarize

I have installed Kubuntu next to Windows 10. Displaying stutters while botch of my monitors are turned on.

### Details

However this problem appear also on other distributions. (Pop OS 20.04 LTS (NVIDIA), KDE Neon, Manjaro).
I thought that only my mouse stutters because when I am moving it, it stops regular and then move again. Furthermore while I am typing or I am watching something on youtube stutters also occurs.

When I turn off my second monitor, everything works fine. I have no stutters, everything is smoothly.

### What I have tried

Full update and upgrade of system.

Installed newest Nvidia drivers from: https://www.nvidia.pl/Download/driverResults.aspx/175963/pl

Set the same resolution and refreshing on both screens.

Turned off HiDPI Daeomon

Removed indicator-multiload
`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove indicator-multiload`

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use the Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux*  found in the on-topic link)

Comment: @guiverc Should I change from Pop OS to Kubuntu and result will be the same? :P
I said I have the same problem on Kubuntu which is one of the flavors.
Firstly I have installed kubuntu. I had this problem then I switched to  PopOS which is based on Ubuntu and result is the same.

Comment: Kubuntu is on-topic & using what Ubuntu have deemed *stable* software. Pop OS doesn't use a Ubuntu kernel and is based on a *testing* grade kernel (eg. Ubuntu on 20.04 will get the kernel Pop OS use on release of 20.04.3, and *development* software is off-topic here until release). Pop also compile the kernel themselves, thus your kernel modules (drivers) maybe different. Pop OS is thus off-topic here, and your software stack is different. (Neon likewise use a different stack & is off-topic, but it's using the Ubuntu kernel with other software changed.. See first comment as to what's on-topic)